# Favorite popular math book

Tags: soft-question, books, popularization, big-list

Christmas is almost here, so imagine you want to buy a good popular math book for your aunt (or whoever you want). Which book would you buy or recommend?

It would be nice if you could answer in the following way:

**Title:** The Poincaré Conjecture: In Search of the Shape of the Universe
**Author:** Donal O'Shea 
**Short description:** The history of the Poincaré Conjecture.
(Perhaps something like "difficulty level": + (no prior knowledge of math, as the book mentioned above), ++ (some prior knowledge of math is helpful), +++ (Roger Penrose: Road to Reality (?))

I hope this is appropriate for MO, since I think is of interest to mathematicians (at least for those who want to buy a popular math book for some aunt :-) ).

Answer (score 63):

**Title:**  Godel, Escher, Bach: an Eternal Golden Braid

**Author:**  Douglas Hofstadter

**Short Description:**  It's mildly debatable whether this is in fact a book about mathematics, but any mathematician who has read this book will understand why I recommend it and any who has not should.  Probably best for those with either a philosophical or musical bent.

Comment: I think Hofstadter would himself say that it is not about mathematics. And I'd say that he was wrong.

Comment: I must be one of the few people who disrecommend the book.  He draws some philosophical conclusions using arguments which have subtle philosophical gaps which are hard for a layman (to philosophy) reader to spot, and gives no hint there could be controversy.  It is a legitimate argument that the gaps I mentioned are not actually gaps at all, but also a legitimate argument that they are.  (Mathematical analogy for the kind of subtle error: confusing an abstract group with one of its faithful matrix representations.)

Comment: Admittedly I'm no expert on philosophy.  I just think GEB has a lot of interesting ideas in it, and Hofstadter presents them very artfully.

Comment: Indeed a very nice book. However, although I know many people who read it, I don't know a single one who doesn't have a degree in math (non of them had when they read it). Is your aunt up to it ?

Comment: @Woo Is there perhaps discussion somewhere on these issues that you could point me too. I am about a third of the way through and would like to hear some of these arguments, since I am as you say a "layman to philosophy". Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I agree with @Woo that there are suspect philosophical arguments in GEB. Hofstadter would probably say that these arguments are more important than the mathematics. And yet I would still recommend GEB for the mathematics it contains.

Comment: Some chapters are better than others. I couldn't really get into the DNA typography stuff, but I loved a lot of other sections of the book.

Comment: It's lovely, but many people complain about the formal logic stuff, which gets pretty heavy at times. Even mathematically inclined people. (Not me though, I've read it three times at least!)

Comment: Math or no math, it's a fun and playful book to read.

Comment: V'Arnold would be very angry at calling "confusion of abstract groups with (faithful) matrix representations" a subtle mistake. If Euler could have understood the question, he would probably laugh a lot too. I wonder if those "subtle philosophical gaps" are similarly deep enough to destroy the conclusions of the book...

Comment: My mother, who is intelligent and very well-read but not comfortable with mathematics, found the book hard-going. 

Answer (score 61):

**Title:** Flatland

**Author:** A. Square / Edwin A. Abbot

**Short Description:** Imagine how life would be in less than three dimensions.

Comment: Jean-Pierre Luminet's "The Wraparound Universe" is a relatively new publication that's kind of in the same direction.  Only it's souped-up by general relativity, geometrization of 3-manifolds and some serious physical experiments.  I just got it in the mail today but it looks promising. 

Comment: Bundle it with "Flatland:The Movie", http://www.flatlandthemovie.com. Your aunt will not be disappointed!

Comment: I first read Flatland when I was 11 or 12, and to me it was an invitation to imagine encounters with beings who live in *more* than three dimensions! It was a real eye-opener. 

Comment: It must be mentioned that at least some knowledge of Victorian society is needed to fully appreciate the satire, though.

Comment: Much more satisfying for a modern reader is The Planiverse, by Dewdney (<a href=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Planiverse>see Wikipédia</a>)

Answer (score 61):

**Title:** Logicomix: An epic search for truth

**Authors:**  Apostolos Doxiadis, Christos Papadimitriou

**Artists:** Alecos Papadatos, Annie Di Donna

**Short description:** A comic book biography of Bertrand Russell, focusing on his work on the foundation of mathematics. (About 345 pages. I just started reading it, so I haven't formed a firm opinion on it yet, but I like what I see so far.)

Comment: This is a great book. They take some liberties with historical accuracy (as they explain in an appendix) but turn it into a compelling story. The characterization of the main players is excellent.

Answer (score 52):

**Title:** Mathematics: A very short introduction

**Author:** Timothy Gowers

**Short description:** As the title says, *very short*. Gives the non-mathematical reader a good idea what mathematics is all about in just about 100 small pages.

Comment: I've read it, and it is near perfect (there are just one or two paragraphs that I would have said otherwise).

Answer (score 40):

**Title:** The Man Who Loved Only Numbers

**Author:** Paul Hoffman

**Short Description:** A biography of Paul Erdős. No previous knowledge of math.

Comment: Although, those that knew him claimed he loved many things...

Comment: This is the most delightful biography I have read, of anyone in any field.

Answer (score 38):

"classic"

**Title:** Fermat's Enigma: The Epic Quest to Solve the World's Greatest Mathematical Problem (US)
Fermat's Last Theorem: The story of a riddle that confounded the world's greatest minds for 358 years (UK)

**Author:** Simon Singh

**Short Description:** The history of Fermat's Theorem, from the famous note *"It is impossible to separate a cube into two cubes, or a fourth power into two fourth powers, or in general, any power higher than the second into two like powers. I have discovered a truly marvellous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain."* to the solution of the Taniyama-Shimura-Conjecture by Andrew Wiles.

By the way, the video [Fermat's Last Theorem (1996)](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=8269328330690408516#) is based on the book.

Comment: I'd also recommend whatever else Simon Singh has written, it's all good. The most mathematical of his other works is The Code Book (aka. The Cracking Code Book, apparently the same book), which I suppose is mathematical enough.

Answer (score 36):

**Title:**  A Mathematician's Apology

**Author:** G. H. Hardy

**Short Description:** In the style of Plato and Xenophon, G. H. Hardy offers a justification for pure mathematics.

Comment: Really?  I personally don't think this book has aged well.  In particular his remarks about number theory being useless for warfare are completely off in light of WWII.

Comment: Let me instead counter-suggest Ian Stewart's "Letters to a Young Mathematician," which is in some sense a response to Mathematician's Apology (which is why I'm not putting it down as a separate answer).

Comment: I also didn't like the snobbery that Hardy displays prominently throughout the book.

Comment: There is no doubt about the snobbery, Akhil... Thing is Hardy was the most prominent English mathematician of the epoch. All in all, I kind of agree with t0rajir0u and would rather be given a copy of Littlewood's Miscellany or the Selected Expository Writing of P. R. Halmos.

Comment: You know what a curious trait of the Apology is? Despite of its huge number of detractors, it is (easy) one of the most quoted texts throughout...

Comment: Akhil Mathew, it's actually a really complicated book, and saying, "oh, snobbery!" is just nonsense.

Comment: Qiaochu, Ian Stewart is a terrible author.  His textbooks are really just trash of the worst kind, but I guess you've got to make a living.  

Comment: Hardy would be surprised by the central role number theory has in modern cryptography and electronic commerce.

Comment: I don't know anything about Stewart's textbooks, but his popular writing is apparently widely recognized.  I guess I should clarify my remark above - what I really mean is that I think it would be easy for a non-mathematician to get a slightly skewed impression of mathematics from the Apology.

Comment: Sure, but apology has a place in history as a great piece of writing, math-related or not.

Comment: @fpqc: Yes, of course there's some good stuff in it.  But I doubt it'd make a good present for the snobbery reason.

Comment: I think you're being somewhat unfair about the snobbery. Hardy is without doubt a fool in a number of respects,  (as well as being a phenomenal mathematician) but this book was written quite obviously in despair, and that I think gives it a unique, touching quality most popular books about math fail to attain.

Comment: @KM: Agreed.  The combination of lucid mathematical insight and unguarded description of personal darkness make it an absolutely unique and unforgettable book.  I try to return to it once every few years as with _Catcher In the Rye_, _Hamlet_ and other great literary works.  (It is remarkable to me that some people simply repeat Hardy's gloomy pronouncements about old mathematicians as though they came out of a sober how-to guide.)

Comment: As Kevin McGerty and Pete Clark say, *A Mathematician's Apology* is an extremely personal and vivid essay by a phenomenal mathematician who was believed himself a has-been. I love it, but I wouldn't want to give it to a nonmathematician with the message "This is what math is about!"

Comment: Yes, a perfect Christmas gift -- a depressing book written by a person who appeared to have had no life outside mathematics and cricket, had a rather bizarre view of what mathematics was about, and was essentially suicidal at the time of writing. A far, far better book is Littlewood's "Mathematical Miscellany.

Comment: @Igor: I don't think that the book itself is depressing, although the introduction (not written by Hardy) surely is.

Comment: Should we expect this question to get answers and comments every year in December?  That's how it's working so far.

G. H. Hardy's opinion of the book titled _Mathematics for the Million_ by the polymath Lancelot Hogben seems to be the exact opposite of David Mumford's opinion of that book.  Where would those opining in this thread rank that book?

Comment: I upvoted this because of the discussion that follows.

Comment: I'm not so sure Akhil is being unfair about the snobbery. I recall various somewhat sneering references to Hogben's book. It's also hard to tell how despairing the book is without having in one's head the back-story provided by Snow, which verges on Too Much Information. (Poor L. Hogben -- another guy who really dished it out to him was George Orwell in Politics and the English Language.) 


Answer (score 35):

**Title:** The Book of Numbers.

**Author:** John Conway and Richard Guy.

**Short Description:**  A beautifully illustrated book with all sorts of facts about all sorts of numbers.  The difficulty is variable throughout the book: parts are written at a + level, while other parts are closer to +++.

Answer (score 30):

**Title:** Journey Through Genius

**Author:** William Dunham

**Short Description:** A fencepost history of mathematics.  For each highpoint it describes some fun history and then the actual math.  Examples of topics covered are Heron's formula for triangular area, Euler's evaluation of $\zeta(2)$ and Cantor's set theory.

Comment: Dunham is a great writer. I also liked his book "Euler: The Master of us All" a lot.

Comment: This book made me want to study mathematics!

Comment: I do not know of any better choice than this one.  It is spellbinding.

Comment: I don't like the title - that genius cult in mathematics is a horrible thing in my opinion.

Comment: Good point about the title, I still love the book though.

Answer (score 30):

**Title:** Fearless Symmetry

**Authors:** Avner Ash and Robert Gross

**Short Description:** Very much a +++ text, these guys actually got a pop-math account of Galois representation theory published! By far the most technically demanding pop-math book I've ever read, (and one that took me about three years to actually finish) it nonetheless makes for a compelling "non-technical" introduction to a beautiful subject.

Comment: The table of contents of this book is enough to make me want to read it!

Comment: This is a pop book? I just looked at the table of contents, and it looks like I could learn a lot from this...and now I'm off to add it to my wishlist on amazon...

Comment: I'm with Qiaochu on this. That is a captivating table of contents.

Answer (score 29):

**Title:** [Innumeracy: Mathematical Illiteracy and its Consequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innumeracy_%28book%29)

**Author:** [John Allen Paulos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Allen_Paulos), mathematician and well-known skeptic (in the good, modern sense of the word).

**Short description:** Paulos explains for the general public (and he does it fairly well) why it should understand a little more mathematics and know how to do Fermi calculations and educated probabilistic guesses. The dangers coming from pseudosciences are also highlighted, something very needed nowadays in my opinion.

**Math level:** +. Some chapters are not that easy to read without a mathematical background, more because of the great number of calculations and logic steps involved in the explanations than because of the math level of those *per se*.

**Price:** 9.89$ at [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0809058405).

Comment: Seconded.  This is a very necessary book.

Comment: +1 I enjoyed skimming this book, which I found lying around a nonmathematician's house, so it's also appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 26):

**Title:** The Lady or the Tiger?

**Author:** Raymond Smullyan

**Short Description:** If your aunt is young enough not to scorn the fairy-tales, this book is a charming collection of logic puzzles, presented under a guise of an entertaining story. The book presuppose no knowledge of mathematics (so difficulty is +), but it ends with a version of Godel's incompleteness theorem. Your aunt will be delighted!

**Remark:** Other books by Smullyan are also great, and will relieve you from wondering of what to give to your aunt for the next few Christmases.

Comment: Agreed, Smullyan is great.  I also liked **Chess Mysteries of Sherlock Holmes**, although this isn't really a book about chess, but retrograde analysis.  

Answer (score 25):

**Title:** Proofs and Refutations - The Logic of Mathematical Discovery

**Author:** Imre Lakatos

**Short Description:** A Plato-esque dialogue between a teacher and his students, aiming to discuss how mathematical discovery happens, how mathematical arguments take form and how mathematical knowledge arises. The discussion is based around the Euler-characteristic, starting off with a concrete conjecture about polyhedra, expanding into the result in full-blown generality through investigation, trial-and-error, the occasional side-track and creative injections as it happens in real life. The book is also sprinkled with mathematical in-jokes, and interesting historical facts about the result. This is a real gem that I keep on my bedside table. Probably at the higher end of the ++ spectrum.

I'm not sure if I'd get the book for my aunt. It takes mathematical reasoning skills to get though the argument and an understanding of why the questions above are worth answering in the first place. I might get it for a philosophically inclined friend instead.

Comment: That is indeed a very good book, but it is (a version of) a doctoral dissertation in philosophy. I don't think anybody can read it who do not have some experience with mathematical proof!


Answer (score 22):

**Title:** Letters to a Young Mathematician

**Author:** Ian Stewart

**Description:** A beautiful book in which Stewart tries to convey in the form of letters from a mathematician to his grand daughter what sort of things does the profession of mathematics involves. It is very interesting since the letters advance from the time in which the grand daughter is in high school up until she is a professional mathematician doing research. I would recommend it without a doubt.

From my own experience it has been really nice to come to this book at different times during the past years. I started college as an engineering student but on my third year I started taking courses from the mathematics program and I bought and read this book when I was just beginning. I had no real idea of what pure mathematics was all about (since I was used to the kind of calculus courses in which the emphasis is on computation rather than proving things) and this book gave me at least some perspective and a few hints of what may be ahead of me.

Just for the record, I ended up switching my major to mathematics.

Answer (score 20):

Title: Prime Obsession

Author: John Derbyshire

Short Description: A book about the Riemann Hypothesis. Its been a while since I read this book, but I remember it being well-written and fun to read. It is very accessible, explaining everything. I think half of the chapters have no math (just facts about Riemann's personal life and such), while the rest is avery gentle introduction to math ideas (like infinite series).

[http://www.amazon.com/Prime-Obsession-Bernhard-Greatest-Mathematics/dp/0452285259/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1260570418&sr=8-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0452285259)

Comment: I would rather read the account of a pro:

Marcus du Sautoy, The Music of the Primes.

Comment: *The Music of the Primes* and *Prime Obsession* are about essentially the same topic, but they're very different books. *The Music of the Primes* is a "+", but *Prime Obsession* is probably "++" (for difficulty level). I thought both were reasonably entertaining. 

Answer (score 20):

**Title**: Gamma : Exploring Euler's constant

**Author** : Julian Havil

**Short description**: Provides a fascinating history of a constant that doesn't get nearly as much attention as $e$ or $\pi$. Definitely has more math than most books intended for a general audience but I feel the book is accessible to those who persevere with it. And the reward is lots and lots of beautiful mathematics.

Comment: What a fantastic book! It's easily one of the main driving forces that got me into analytic number theory. 

Answer (score 19):

**Title:** Uncle Petros and Goldbach's Conjecture

**Author:** Apostolos Doxiadis

**Short Description:** It is a very fun novel based on the life of a fictional character who spends most of his live trying to prove Goldbach's conjecture. It talks about some other famous problems in math. This novel is fun for mathematicians and non-mathematicians. No knowledge of math is required.

Comment: Indeed it is one of the best math-fiction story ever!

Answer (score 18):

**Title:** The Symmetries of Things

**Authors:**  John Horton Conway, Heidi Burgiel, and Chaim Goodman-Strauss

**Description:**  The authors begin by introducing the general concept of geometric symmetry / regular tiling, and then pose the problem of classifying all possible symmetries of the plane.  They provide an elegant topological classification, and along the way introduce the notions of orbifold and classify the compact surfaces with boundary.  It's then easy enough to also classify the discrete symmetries of the sphere.  In part II, the authors introduce the notion abstract group, and classify the prime-order "color symmetries" of the plane, which are tiling patterns with different-colored tiles.  Part III consists of a discussion of higher-dimensional tilings, including the four-dimensional Archimedean solids.

Part I is suitable for an interested amateur with no specific prior knowledge.  Part II is at an advanced undergraduate level, although it does contain new results.  Part III, which is about half the book, is research level.  The book is printed in full-color.

Answer (score 18):

**Title:** The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time.

**Author:** Mark Haddon.

**Description:** A mathematically gifted kid tries to solve the mystery of a dog murdered in the night-time.

**Remark:** Although this isn't a math book per se, it actually does contain a lot of interesting and non-trivial mathematics.  Also, it's very well illustrated.  As a final selling point, you have to respect any book whose chapters are indexed by the primes.

Comment: In my opinion, this looks more like a *murder novel* than an introductory or public mathematical book for an **aunt** to learn some math, any way, it is quite an enjoyment to read the book.

Answer (score 16):

**Title:** Symmetry and the Monster

**Author:** Mark Ronan

**Short Description:** The history of the classification of finite simple groups. Reads like a good novel.

Comment: A beautiful book.  Though I'm biased, as an undergrad at Rutgers, I met a few of the major players in this story.  One of my first recommendations to people when they ask me "You're an algebraist? What's that?"

Answer (score 16):

Title: **The Mathematical Experience**

Authors: **Davis and Hirsh**

Short Description: A really accessible and funny introduction to the philosophy of mathematics.  I think the description of the "ideal mathematician" is particularly hilarious.

Answer (score 16):

**Title:** Indiscrete Thoughts

**Author:** Gian-Carlo Rota

**Description:** General discussion on Mathematics, Princeton of the fiftees, lives of Artin, Feller and of Rota's intimate friend Stanislaw Ulam; fantastic bedtime reading. Also includes philosophical flavour like '10 things I had been taught' type.

Comment: This is one of my favorite books, but the philosophy section is a little too heavy to be called "popular" writing.

Comment: Actually, I think some of the philosophy section would be of more interest to a general cultivated audience than most of the rest of the book, which might be interesting to mathematicians and academics but perhaps not to many others. 


Answer (score 16):

**Title:** The Code Book

**Author:** Simon Singh

**Description:** This is a popularized history of cryptography and cryptanalysis. It runs the range from shift-ciphers to modern public key cryptosystems and quantum key distribution. No prior knowledge of maths is necessary, but can be helpful.

It has been quite some time since I read this book, but I found it incredibly engaging at the time. I know it isn't strictly focused on mathematics, but I am surprised that no one else has mentioned it.

Comment: In my opinion the greatest fragment of the book is explanation of reconstruction of linear letters of B ( or A, I do not remember) of Cretan people.

Comment: This book also exists under the name The Cracking Code Book, apparently.

Answer (score 15):

Title: What is mathematics?

Author: Herbert Robbins and Richard Courant

This book is a very nice introduction to mathematics, it covers basic number theory, analysis, algebra, geometry and topology.

I'am very surprised that i couldn't find it on this list already.

(from a duplicate answer - feel free to edit) This would be for someone who has some mathematical ability, and really wants to understand what math is. Courant goes through essentially all of mathematics, starting at a very elementary level, but getting to some very deep and important stuff. He often does real proofs, and doesn't dumb it down, but does explain things conceptually very well, including sometimes giving just ideas or justifications for really difficult things, like the prime number theorem. I use this when I teach our senior proof seminar, just to force the math majors to own a copy.

Comment: I copy-pasted a description from a duplicate answer, since the previous description was a bit brief.  Anyone who wants to clean it up should do so.

Answer (score 14):

**Title**: The honors class: Hilbert's problems and their Solvers

**Author**: Ben Yandell

**Short description**: The title says it all. It gets dense at times, but it has an enormous range of topics and the biographies are very interesting. Probably a ++.

Comment: This is really a great book!

Answer (score 14):

Title: Euler's Gem: The Polyhedron Formula and the Birth of Topology

Author: David S. Richeson

Short Description: V-E+F=2. Requires little (no?) preparation, but some willingness to think. I gave it to a few people who wanted to know more about what math really was (as opposed to adding longer and longer columns of numbers, as my mother believes), and those who made the investment of their time came away with a  much better understanding.

Comment: I finally got around to reading this!  It is really, really fantastic.

Comment: I agree fully with Qiaochu Yuan's comment above. It's a wonderful book, starting with polyhedra and ending with a touch of algebraic topology (and the Poincaré Conjecture in the epilogue).  

Answer (score 14):

**Title:** What is the name of this book?

**Author:** Raymond Smullyan

**Short description:** Lots and lots of logical puzzles (the kind with people always telling the truth, people always lying, people who sometimes tell the truth and sometimes lie, etc.) It is really entertaining, and it serves well as an introduction to the logic of propositions.

Answer (score 12):

**Title:** King of Infinite Space: Donald Coxeter, the Man Who Saved Geometry

**Author:** Siobhan Roberts

**Short Description:** Biography of Coxeter.

Answer (score 12):

**Title:** Everything and More: A Compact History of Infinity

**Author:** David Foster Wallace

**Short description:** History of the idea of infinity, mostly leading up to Cantor's set theory ideas. It's been awhile since I've read this but I would say the mathematics is pretty decent for popular writing and the writing is really enjoyable if you like Wallace's style (and maddening if you can't stand him, I'm sure). This is the kind of math book you could get for someone who enjoys serious literature.

No prior knowledge is necessary, but the math-phobic could struggle.

Comment: Unfortunately Wallace didn't fully understand much of what he wrote about, and made some serious errors.

Answer (score 12):

Title:  Men of Mathematics

Author: E. T. Bell

Short Description:  Short biographies (~30?) of important mathematicians.  Excellent relations of the death of Archimedes, Galois' temper, Newton's eccentricities, &c.  Also try his (Edit: actually L. Hogben's) book Mathematics for the Millions.

Comment: A fun read, but not to be taken seriously as history. 

Comment: You are absolutely right, Gerry.  Not that good history must always be literally true . . .

Comment: Early editions of this book are not exactly politically correct by today's standards.

Comment: Belated comment: good history should have regard for truth/accuracy

Comment: A couple of my friends chose mathematics as there career becuause of this book :)

Answer (score 11):

**Title:** Mathematics and the Imagination

**Authors:** Edward Kasner and James Newman

**Short Description:** A number of chapters covering lots of subjects: counting numbers (including the coining of the word "googol"); $\pi$, $i$, and $e$; geometries, plane and "fancy" ("Lobachevsky's Eiffel Towers and Riemann's Holland Tunnels"); puzzles; paradoxes; chance and probability; topology ("rubber sheet geometry"); calculus. Very much in the spirit of Martin Gardner columns, but from before *they* existed (the book was originally published in 1940; Gardner began writing his columns in 1956).  You can see a preview at [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ad8hAx-6m9oC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22mathematics+and+the+imagination%22&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=-VwATYPHEMK78gaeq5WVDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Which also leads me to

**Author:** Martin Gardner

**Title:** Various

**Short Description:** A joy to read.

Answer (score 11):

Ian Stewart is a very good mathematics popularizer and I understand why many of his books are in this list.  But I really don't understand why none of Martin Gardner's books are listed here (at the time I'm writing this).

My favorite Martin Gardner book (actually, an updated collection of Scientific American Mathematical Games columns) is **The Colossal Book of Mathematics**.  From the book's cover: "Number Theory, Algebra, Geometry, Probability, Topology, Game Theory, Infinity, and other topics of recreational mathematics."  I would say its difficulty level is "+".

Answer (score 10):

**Title:** Why Beauty is Truth: A History of Symmetry

**Author:** Ian Stewart

**Brief Description:** Stewart surveys the history of symmetry in mathematics (from ancient times to present day). There is particular emphasis on the insolvability of the quintic, the invention of Galois theory, and its impact on modern mathematics.

Answer (score 10):

Title: The I Hate Mathematics! Book

Author: Marilyn Burns

Short Description: The google.books description is well written. A book for nonbelievers. I had this as a kid, and i remember its questions and pictures having an effect on me. How many sides does a banana have and how can 4 colours colour this map.

Comment: Upvoted because I loved this book as a kid (despite not hating math!) and haven't thought about it in thirty years.

Answer (score 9):

**Title:** An Imaginary Tale

**Author:** Paul Nahin

**Short Description:** This book is primarily about complex numbers.  I can't remember it that well, but most of the book doesn't require calculus (though a fair part definitely does).    Most of it is about the algebra and geometry of complex numbers and is thus accessible to the nonmathematician.  The last chapter has a very fun introduction to complex analysis.

Comment: This book is/was riddled with errors. He released a second edition at the behest of R.B. Burckel, and from what he has told me, none of the corrections were made. I understand that this book is pop-math, and thus the reader may not be desiring of great precision. However, most of the errors contained therein could have been omitted without disruption of the colloquial style or prose.

Comment: I read this one in high school and didn't like it.  The errors were a serious problem, and the exposition felt dry to me.

Answer (score 9):

Wonder why it is that nobody has mentioned **Lion-Hunting & Other Mathematical Pursuits**? That book is one of my all-time favorites.

The book was edited by **Gerald L. Alexanderson**, the same individual behind [the random walks of G. Pólya](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883855283). Not only does the book contain the original article that launched the *theory of big game hunting* as a branch of mathematical research of its own, but also several of the subsequent contributions motivated by that 1938 groundbreaking paper of H. Pétard, e.g.:

- If there is an even number of lions in the Sahara Desert we add a tame lion. Thus we may assume that the group of the Sahara lions is of odd order. This renders the situation capable of solution according to the work of Feit and Thompson.

Comment: Is this book one such that it contains a way to capture lions using inverse mappings?It seems to be pretty fun and may I ask what level does it require?


Answer (score 9):

**Title:** [The Man Who Counted](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393309347) (translated from Portuguese)

**Author:** Malba Tahan

**Short description:**  A mixture of Arabian Nights and a classical puzzlebook. The stories follow a brilliant youth who solves mathematical problems. A highly enjoyable read for anyone who likes oriental tales, and just the right combination of adventures and mathematics for all aunts and nephews out there without a mathematics degree.

*Malba Tahan* is a pen name of the Brazilian mathematician and writer [Júlio César de Mello e Souza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%BAlio_C%C3%A9sar_de_Mello_e_Souza). The book was first published as *O homem que calculava* in 1949.

Answer (score 8):

**Title:** Hilbert

**Author:** Constance Reid

**Description:** Biography of David Hilbert. Fascinating. Don't have to be D.H. to enjoy it. [the following is added from a duplicate answer - feel free to clean up -- ed.] A beautiful biography of a famous mathematician, showing the passion for knowledge represented by Hilbert and others at Goettingen around 1900. The book has a good description of Hilbert as a person, describes his family and coworkers and (sadly) the decay at the end of Hibert's life as the Nazis took over. I ask some of my undergraduate students to read this so that they can see the excitement of being in our profession. (The book is out of print, I think, but available via half.com or ebay.)

**Second recommendation** Also, *Time-Life*, ca. 1965, published one of it's picture books on math, titled of all things
*Mathematics* (as I recall). Check it out if you can find it. Lots of cool pictures. Great
for mathematically inclined high school kids.

Note added in edit:  The aforementioned book from the *Time-Life* series also had great
pictures of mathematicians. As I recall, there was one of Eilenberg lying on the couch
of his Grenwich Village apartment, coat and tie still on. It was captioned with a quote which
went, if I recall correctly, "Sometimes I like to think riding on the subway, but mostly I
like to think lying down." Absolutely formative in my personal approach to math!

Answer (score 8):

What about the Princeton Companion to Mathematics?

It contains alot of introductory information on the spectrum 
of mathematics with historical note. When you need a quick
perspective on branches of mathematics that are less familiar
to you, it is a place to go. The book is divided into sections
on famous mathematicians, theorems, and branches of mathematics
all of which cannot be held by even the most well versed
mathematician.

Answer (score 7):

**Title:** The Art of Mathematics

**Author:** B. Bollobas

**Short Review:** "The Author considers these problems to be the type that two mathematical friends would pose to each other and discuss over a cup of coffee in a lounge. I agree with that premise, they are not too hard and there is a proof that is relatively easy to discover and even easier to understand. These problems satisfy all of the requirements for a good problem..."

This is one of the most entertaining recreation-mathematical books I've ever read. It does require some mathematical knowledge to be fully appreciated though :)

Comment: I don't know about you, but this is a little too dense for my aunt!

Comment: Haha, well I've gotten it as a present that's why it came to mind.
I totally forgot about the aunt part.

Comment: I'm reading this one now and rather like it.  It should be noted that the problems in this book are some that *mathematicians* think about casually -- basically, Bollobas says he was looking for problems that Erdos or Littlewood, the two "great" mathematicians he says he's known, would have liked.  So the level of difficulty is quite high for a "recreational" book.

Comment: Are this book and that by King, Jerry P. the same, thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 7):

**Title:** A tangled tale

**Author:** Lewis Carroll

**Description:** (by Carroll himself in the preface) The writer’s intention was to embody in each Knot (like medicine so dexterously, but ineffectually, concealed in the jam of our early childhood) one or more mathematical questions — in Arithmetic, Algebra, or Geometry, as the case might be — for the amusement, and possible edification, of the fair readers of that magazine.

Of course, this will work as a gift for a niece better than a gift for an aunt, but it is one of those few books (the only other ones I know are by Smullyan and they've been mentioned already) that have both an entertaining story line and some actual mathematical challenges for the reader in them and that require no special mathematical training to read and enjoy.

Answer (score 6):

**Title:** Perfect Rigor: A Genius and the Mathematical Breakthrough of the Century

**Author:** Masha Gessen

**Short Description:** Story of Grigory Perelman based on information from people who interacted with him. A lot of interesting stuff about life in general and mathematics education in particular in Soviet Union around 1980's. There is only one or two short chapters where the author tries to explain the mathematics but if you skip those you don't need any serious mathematical skills.

Answer (score 6):

**Title:** The Mathematician's Brain

**Author:** David Ruelle

**Short description:** (++) A book describing how Mathematics are founded, and tries to give a reasoning for the brain-work needed to do math.

**From Amazon:** The Mathematician's Brain poses a provocative question about the world's most brilliant yet eccentric mathematical minds: were they brilliant because of their eccentricities or in spite of them? In this thought-provoking and entertaining book, David Ruelle, the well-known mathematical physicist who helped create chaos theory, gives us a rare insider's account of the celebrated mathematicians he has known-their quirks, oddities, personal tragedies, bad behavior, descents into madness, tragic ends, and the sublime, inexpressible beauty of their most breathtaking mathematical discoveries.

Answer (score 5):

**Title** : The Parrot's Theorem (Le théorème du perroquet)

**Author** : Denis Guedj

**Description** : I read this while in high school, it's kind of a murder mystery, and it revolves around a family who has a mathematician friend who was trying to solve the Goldbach conjecture and Fermat's last theorem before he died. It includes many fun mathematics and is presented in a very light to read manner.

Answer (score 4):

Title: Recoltes et Semailles (Reapings and Sowings)
Author: Alexander Grothendieck

Description: Grothendieck's autobiography and self-assessment as a mathematician and a person.

Comment: I don't know if I'd call this "popular".

Comment: For sure this is an interesting book, first time I read first section then I was 18 I loved it. Second time I read it when I was 25-27 I hated it. Maybe it is time to read it again :)

Answer (score 4):

I like Mario Livio's books:

The Golden Ratio: The Story of PHI, the World's Most Astonishing Number

and

The Equation That Couldn't Be Solved: How Mathematical Genius Discovered the Language of Symmetry

Answer (score 4):

**Title**: *The Magical Maze*

**Author**: Ian Stewart

**Short description**: Various bits of counterintuitive, fundamental, and/or easily understood mathematics, to wit: modular arithmetic, Fibonacci numbers, depth-first search, the axiomatic method, the Monty Hall problem, the birthday paradoxes, wallpaper groups, cellular automata, dynamical systems, formalism, Godel incompleteness, Turing's halting problem, optimization problems (both continuous and discrete), algorithmic complexity, fractals, chaos, and Hausdorff dimension.

This book is, to a large extent, the reason I am in graduate school right now. I read it in the eighth grade, and now here I am.

Answer (score 4):

Title: Satan, Cantor & Infinity

Author: Raymond M. Smullyan

Short Description: Another gem in the list of Smullyan's books. If you love "logical sorcery", this is a perfect gift for you.

Answer (score 4):

**Title** One Two Three . . . Infinity: Facts and Speculations of Science

**Author** George Gamow

**Short description** While not limited to mathematics, this is a great book which presents some subtle mathematical ideas in an intuitive non-technical way. I especially like the presentation of Cantor's infinite cardinality theory, which can be followed by anyone. Unfortunately, there are some mistakes. I seem to recall his presentation implicitly assumes the continuum hypothesis, but maybe he did that for clarity. It doesn't really detract from the book.

Answer (score 4):

I see many favorites here, but this one should be mentioned too:

MR1710978 (2000h:00002) Hugo Steinhaus. Mathematical snapshots. Translated from the Polish. With a preface by Morris Kline. Reprint of the third (1983) English edition. Dover Publications, Inc., Mineola, NY, 1999. vi+311 pp. ISBN: 0-486-40914-7

It was first published in 1939 ("Kalejdoskop matematyczny" in Polish).

Here is the summary:

http://books.google.com/books?id=N63XpD1oJ6IC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Things like fair division or platonic bodies made accessible for an aunt and a niece alike (I actually gave my copy to my niece a few years ago).

Answer (score 3):

**Title:**  Wonders of Numbers: Adventures in Mathematics, Mind, and Meaning

**Author:**  Clifford A. Pickover

**Short Description:**  A wonderful collection of historical anecdotes, mathematical trivia, and puzzles.  I would especially recommend this if you were shopping for a younger relative.

Comment: I do like the books by Pickover very much. I think he is very over-looked.

Answer (score 3):

**Title:** Another Fine Math You've Got Me Into

**Author:** Ian Stewart.

**Short Description:**  Mathematical puzzle columns, (originally for the French version of *Scientific American*) some of which introduce interesting concepts from higher mathematics.  Ian Stewart has written a lot in this vein (as have others, e.g. Martin Gardner), but this book is my favorite and is one of the mathematically meatiest of them (in my opinion).

I'd say this is a ++.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recomend "The Pea and the Sun, a mathematical paradox" which roughly explains the proof of Bannach-Tarski Theorem, which is a consequence of the axiom of choice and roughly says that you can break a pea in a finite number of pieces, tehn reassemble the pieces and get the sun

Answer (score 3):

My favourite books are:

- $\text{I want to be a Mathematician}$ by Paul Halmos.
- *Problems for Mathematicians, young and old,* by the same author.
- *The Man who knew Infinity*: : A Life of the Genius Ramanujan by Robert Kanigel.  Fanastatic book. Covers almost all of Ramanujan's life and work. Certainly a must read.

Answer (score 2):

**Title:**  Euclid's Window

**Author:**  Leonard Mlodinow

**Short Description:**  A history of geometry of sorts.  It's very well-written and was one of my favorite math books growing up.  But you should read the [Table of Contents](http://books.google.com/books?id=GHY6VM3NsIwC&dq=euclid%27s+window&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=LFPg7kErjP&sig=7TUUvAZJqFgsgWe3gfVQHpRz1zY&hl=en&ei=gsYiS8qRJ5G1tgfxlPnhBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAw) to actually get an idea of what the book is about.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that there are dissenting opinions on this book, e.g. the following review by Langlands: http://publications.ias.edu/rpl_works/L12/euclid/euclid-ps.pdf

Comment: Interesting.  I read this book when I was very young and haven't since, so perhaps my opinion would change if I gave it another look.

Answer (score 2):

**Title:** Introduction to Mathematical Thinking: The Formation of Concepts in Modern Mathematics

**Author:** Friedrich Waismann

**Short Description:** This book, first published in 1936, gives an introduction to the philosophy of mathematics and the foundations of analysis. It shows how to construct number systems, some very elementary set theory and how to make differential calculus precise. The focus is on concepts. It includes a discussion of things like continuuous, nowhere differentiable functions and discusses why R and R<sup>2</sup> are isomorphic as sets but not topologically. It even gives an very short and intuitive proof that R and R<sup>2</sup> are not homeomorphic.

The philosophical discussion is, naturally, a litlle bit dated. It discusses formalism, logicism and intuitivism. The philosophy still makes for exciting historical reading. It is clear that this discussion was very lively when this book was written.

The level should youalify as ++, the book is demanding but can certainly be read before going to college.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late for Christmas, but nevertheless, I have a few (some of which have already been mentioned) books I've read that I've quite enjoyed.  For the sake of brevity, I'll let you search the titles on Amazon for reviews and better descriptions.

Title: Everything & More: A Compact History of Infinity
Author: David Foster Wallace

Title: The Mathematical Experience
Author(s): Philip J Davis & Reuben Hersh

Title: One, Two, Three...Infinity
Author: George Gamow

Title: Pi in the Sky
Author: John D. Barrow

Title: Prime Obsession: Bernhard Riemann and the Greatest Unsolved Problem in Mathematics
Author: John Derbyshire

Title: Strength in Numbers
Author: Sherman Stein

Title: e: The Story of a Number
Author: Eli Maor

Title: A History of Pi
Author: Petr Beckmann

Title: Nature's Numbers
Author: Ian Stewart

Title: Mathematics: The Science of Patterns
Author: Keith Devlin

Title: Zero: The Biography of a Dangerous Idea
Author: Charles Seife

Title: How to Enjoy Calculus
Author: Eli S. Pine
(Not really a "popular" book, per se', but still pretty good)

Title: How to Think About Weird Things
Author(s): Theodore Schick & Lewis Vaughn
(Not really about mathematics, but not so far out of the way that you wouldn't enjoy it if you also enjoy mathematics)

Answer (score 2):

**Title:** The Mystery of the Aleph: Mathematics, the Kabbalah, and the Search for Infinity

**Author:** Amir D. Aczel

**Short Description:** Another book about the development of ideas about infinity.  The central character is Cantor, of course, but it also looks at people before, like Bolzano and Galileo, and afterwards, including Godel and Cohen for their work on CH.

I read this in high school, having just a little calculus background, and got a lot out of it.  It does try to work in the themes of "contemplation of infinity leads to insanity" and "infinity as religious insight" a bit, which might be drawbacks.  But when I read it for the first time, I remember laughing out loud at how amazing the ideas involving infinte cardinalites and AC were, so at least those are presented well.

Answer (score 2):

**Title**: Prisoner's Dilemma

**Author**: William Poundstone

**Short description** (from New York Times Book Review): The real originality of PRISONER'S DILEMMA lies in its colorful synthesis of logical material and historical and biographical narration [which] takes us in parallel lines through cold war history, strategic games of the nuclear age and the life of von Neumann . . . Lively, open and multifaceted.

Indeed, the book can be read as a whole or just by following one of those "parallel lines". Depending of the line you choose, the level of difficulty would be + or ++!

Answer (score 1):

**Title:** [Mathematics: A Very Short Introduction](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematics-Very-Short-Introduction-Introductions/dp/0192853619)

**Author:** Timothy Gowers

**Short description:** "A marvellously lucid guide to the beauty and mystery of numbers"

This book is excellent for someone who wants to delve in to some basic, but interesting mathematics. It avoids very "popular mathematics" such as chaos theory and focuses in detail on "mundane" topics, such as dimension and estimation.

difficulty level: +

£4.73 on Amazon UK

Comment: This was already posted.

Answer (score 1):

You should not miss this book about algebra.

**Title:** Unknown Quantity

**Author:** John Derbyshire

Not only it explains the rise of algebra since antiquity, it also helps the reader to gain an intuitive approach to think and apply algebra in suitable problems. Great reading experience.